# How can i create kgring file using python?

Tags: python, cprofile

I'm new in python programming. I try to learn cProfiler and using pyprof2calltree . I'm using python 2.7 , windows 7 .I installed pyprof2calltree 1.3.2 and qcachegrind074-x86.The problem is that i coudldn't find any tutorial about using qcachegrind074 in windows and all codes are in another operating systems. I wrote the very simple code(the below code) .I just want to create a kgring but  raised  error !. where is my problem in thi code and how can i create a kgring  file ?

```
def r():
    print range(1,1000)

if __name__ =='__main__':
    from cProfile import Profile
    profiler = Profile()
    profiler.run('r()')

    from pyprof2calltree import convert, visualize
    visualize(profiler.getstats())
    convert(profiler.getstats(), 'c:/profiling_results.kgrind')
```

The errors are :

> Traceback(most recent call last):  File "C:/..../pyprof2example, line
>   11, in   visualize( profiler.getstats() ) File
>   "C:...\lib\pyprof2calltree.py, line 306, in visualize
>   converter.visualize() File "C:...\lib\pyprof2calltree.py", line 145,
>   in visualize self.output(f)   File "C:...\lib\pyprof2calltree.py",
>   line 133, in output
>       self._entry(entry)   File "C:\P...\lib\pyprof2calltree.py", line 208, in _entry
>       for subentry, call_info in calls: ValueError: too many values to unpack

Thanks

Comment: Your first problem is you didn't show full error message. There is number of line with problem - mark this line in code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to execute your code via cmd line. [Here](https://bitbucket.org/ogrisel/pyprof2calltree/issue/3/too-many-values-to-unpack) is the discussion.